# WPF - Set ContentTemplate with static resource child?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am relatively new in MVVM. May i know is that a way i can get the element in my user control and bind it separately in a `ContentTemplate`? I draft a sample code like below.

I have a user control consists of `RedStack`, `GreenStack`, `BlueStack`. My goal is if condition A then show the `RedStack` and `BlueStack` in the `ContentTemplate`, else show all color stacks in the `ContentTemplate`

Color user control :

```
<UserControl x:Class="MapDisplay.ColorView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="RedStack">
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="GreenStack" >
        <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="100" Height="100"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="BlueStack" >
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="100" Height="100"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Main user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication.UserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:MapDisplay;assembly=MapDisplay"
         xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
         mc:Ignorable="d" >

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type custom:ColorController}">
                    <custom:ColorView/>
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate x:Key="ColorDisplay">
                    <Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}" />
                </DataTemplate>

                <ControlTemplate x:Key="SplitColorDisplay">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" 
                           ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ColorDisplay.Colors.RedStack?}" />
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" 
                           ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ColorDisplay.Colors.BlueStack?}"  />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Border>
    <ContentControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="{Binding}">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ColorDisplay}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSplitColor}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SplitColorDisplay}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</Border>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: This looks odd. Your UserControl should expose a property that controls which of its child elements are visible.

Comment: @Clemens, these are just a sample code i provided. The current codes i am building do consists a lot of controls inside the "redstack", "greenstack" and the "bluestack".

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Your UserControl could still expose a property that controls which of its child elements are visible.

Comment: @0070: Create two different data templates and use a `ContentTemplateSelector` to decide when to select which one. You may define the `StackPanels` in separate `UserControls` to be able to use them in both data templates.